# Python multiprocessing into idle state for unknown reason

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I use `multiprocessing.Pool` to parallelize my code. I open 6 processes for my 8-core PC with 16GB RAM. The program is running well (although it is very  computing intensive). Sometimes the RAM is fully charged and swap is used and then the program suddenly falls in idle state, i.e. the program is not quitting nor printing anything, but all CPU is no load, not doing anything, mysteriously. It requires several key strokes to the terminal then it goes back to work or that happens with coincidence and  the program recovers after several minutes. Well, my PC is too tired?! I checked CPU temperature and it's 70, that's normal.

Comment: Without some details about your program, maybe some code, it would be  like reading tea leaves. Maybe there is a deadlock somewhere or a loop thats waits for input.